# php add mins to date

Tags: php, time, strtotime

```
$orderDate = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($result[$x]['date_modified']) );
echo "<br>".$orderDate;
$endTime =date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime('+10 minutes', $orderDate));
echo "<br>".date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $endTime);
```

prints as

28/05/2018 09:27:45 - **This is correct**

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   C:\xampp5.5\htdocs\php\index.php on line 4166
>
> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   C:\xampp5.5\htdocs\php\index.php on line 4167

01/01/1970 12:00:01 - **Why is this not working?**

Comment: why you are formatting `$endTime` again while printing?. It is already formatted

Comment: "_on line 4167_" Your script is that long?

Comment: yeah, I haven't broken anything up

Comment: Sidenote: For dealing with Date modification I recommend using a library as [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub) as it provides a lot of helper methods:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$orderDateTimestamp = strtotime($result[$x]['date_modified']);
$endDateTimeStamp = strtotime('+10 minutes', $orderDateTimestamp);
$orderDate = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $orderDateTimestamp);
$endDate = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $endDateTimeStamp);
echo $orderDate.'<br>'.$endDate;
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) expects second parameter to be an integer (timestamp). Furthermore it accepts as string source not all the formats, such as `d/m/Y` (check also the format of `$result[$x]['date_modified']`, if it comes from MySql resultset you shouldn't have problems as it is `Y-m-d H:i:s`) .
So correct it with this solution and it should work

Comment: Thanks Jack Skeletron and everyone else

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` function will not work for a few date formats and `d/m/Y` is one of those formats. For correct manipulation of date and time one recommended format is the MySQL date format i.e. `YYYY-mm-dd` and further process it.

For further reading: [The strtotime documentation reads](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to accept all type of date and time format

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', '28/05/2018 09:27:45');
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT10M'));
echo $dt->format('d/m/Y h:i:s');
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1011155)